# Where in the body {} are the colors white for the background?

Tags: css

Where in the
body {} are the colors white for the background? (The left and right hand side).

http://www.newyorkimc.com/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you expect the reader of this question to take away from it?

Answer (score 1):

The body’s `background` CSS declaration is ill-formed (incomplete `url`) and thus ignored. Hence the background remains white.

Answer (score 0):

In general, there is no color white needed as white is the default color for any HTML body anyway. The website works using CSS. You can view the CSS for this website by installing Google Chrome and Right-Clicking on Inspect Element.

Here's what this will get you:

```
body {
background: #0CC url repeat-x; <<< fix this part see below for the wrap
color: #444;
font-size: 12px;
font-family: Arial, Tahoma, Verdana;
margin: 0 auto 0;
padding: 0;
line-height: 20px;
}

home #wrap, .home-page #wrap, .blog #wrap {
background: url(http://www.newyorkimc.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/wrap.png) top center no-repeat;
margin: 0 auto 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

As was mentioned in another answer, the body css is malformed and would need to be corrected.